# ERROR: Azure B2C Create user by post method from web application

Tags: c#, azure, crud, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying perform CRUD operation for Azure B2C through MVC application. The following application works for getting user data i.e. `GET` method. But the `POST` method for creating new user is not working. `POST` method is giving response with `Status Code` 400, Reason `Phrase:Bad Request`. I added these two methods to achieve CRUD functionality in the project in GitHub: [Microsoft Graph SDK ASPNET Connect](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-connect-sample)

```
public async Task<string> UpdateUserDetails(string accessToken)
    {
        string jsondata = File.ReadAllText("C:\\usertemplate-email.json");

        string endpoint = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users";
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, endpoint))
            {
                request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
                request.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsondata), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                //didn't received successStatusCode with or without searilizing jasondata
                using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request))
                {
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        //Status Code: 400, Reason Phrase:Bad Request
                        var json = JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

                    }
                    return response.ReasonPhrase;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public async Task<string> GetUserDetails(string accessToken)
    {

        // Get the current user. 
        // The app only needs the user's email address, so select the mail and userPrincipalName properties.
        // If the mail property isn't defined, userPrincipalName should map to the email for all account types. 
        string endpoint = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/4b4442a8-bd02-4992-9c62-b1b31807428d";


        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            //if no queryParameter parameter is passed, all parameters will be selected
            using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, endpoint))
            {
                request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
                using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request))
                {
                    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        var json = JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                      //got the expected result at this point
                    }
                    return response.ReasonPhrase;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The included json file:

```
{
"accountEnabled": true,
"signInNames": [
    {
        "type": "emailAddress",
        "value": "joe123consumer@gmail.com"
    }
],
"creationType": "LocalAccount",
"displayName": "Joe Consumer",
"mailNickname": "joec",
"passwordProfile": {
    "password": "P@ssword!",
    "forceChangePasswordNextLogin": false
},
"passwordPolicies": "DisablePasswordExpiration",


"city": "San Diego",
"country": null,
"facsimileTelephoneNumber": null,
"givenName": "Joe",
"mail": null,
"mobile": null,
"otherMails": [],
"postalCode": "92130",
"preferredLanguage": null,
"state": "California",
"streetAddress": null,
"surname": "Consumer",
"telephoneNumber": null
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I am able to get it done by following the parameters as suggested in the  [microsoft graph api documentation](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_post_users). 
The json data i have used is:
`{"accountEnabled": true,

"displayName": "my, name",

"mailNickname": "emailname",

"userPrincipalName": "tokigston@yourdomain.onmicrosoft.com",

"passwordProfile" : {

    "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": true,

    "password": "P@ssword!"

    }
}`

There should not be space in mailNickname attribute value.
The CreateuserFunction will be:

```
public async Task<string> CreateUser(string accessToken)
    {
        string jsondata = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\\usertemplate-email.json");

        string endpoint = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users";
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var method = new HttpMethod("POST");

            using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, endpoint))
            {
                request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
                request.Content = new StringContent(jsondata.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request))
                {
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        //Status Code: 400, Reason Phrase:Bad Request
                        //On success, it gives Created
                        var json = JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

                    }
                    return response.ReasonPhrase;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you're using the Microsoft Graph API, rather than the Azure AD Graph API.

As far as I'm aware, the Microsoft Graph API doesn't work with B2C.

You want to be using this one: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations

Comment: Thank you  @gfyans. I think it is not because of Microsoft Graph API as I am able to make it work for GET and PATCH methods It may be caused by the nested object in input json data where serialization is causing format error.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that the account you want to add doesn't exit on the tenant before.

The JSON works well for me when I added the account first time. And I could reproduce this issue with 400 error when I try to add it again. Here is the detail error message:
[image]

We can use the Fiddler to capture the request to see the detail error message.

Comment: I am trying to get it done by microsoft graph api (graph.windows.com) not windows.graph.net, so this json data is not working.